# OpenVPN - Unable to route traffic through multiple exit Interface

Tags: iptables, openvpn, wide-area-network

Good evening

I have an OpenVPN Server with 3 Wan IP addresses. For instance:

```
eth0 -- 1.1.1.1
eth0:0 -- 2.2.2.2
eth0:1 -- 3.3.3.3
```

On client OVPN, I have set remote IP `2.2.2.2`.

On OpenVPN server, I have set ip table rule

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.0/24 -o eth0:0 -j SNAT --to 2.2.2.2
```

However, upon connecting to OpenVPN (supposedly via `2.2.2.2`) successfully, my outgoing WAN IP will always be `1.1.1.1`.

What am I missing out? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you will run `iptables -t nat -L -n -v`, you will see zero counters of your rule. It caused invalid interface name (`eth0:0`) in the rule, because the `eth0:0` isn't an interface name, but just alias (deprecate way to use additional addresses on interface).

Your rule should look like:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 2.2.2.2
```

Comment: Thank you Anton. It is still showing ip address 1.1.1.1, despite that I connected I connect from OpenVPN client with remote server of 2.2.2.2.

I believe the issue is pertaining to routing table?

Comment: I have also deleted iptable NAT masquerade rules. The rule that you have stated is the top most rule currently. But it is not working.

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. Other rules also affect. And order of rules is very important. Better paste the full rules of the nat table (`iptables-save -c -t nat`).

Comment: Thank you Anton. Here is the output of the nat table: https://i.imgur.com/M3pMQlF.png